# example of doing simple prediction with pytorch-lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have an existing model where I load some pre-trained weights and then do prediction (one image at a time) in pytorch. I am trying to basically convert it to a pytorch lightning module and am confused about a few things.

So currently, my `__init__` method for the model looks like this:

```
self._load_config_file(cfg_file)
# just creates the pytorch network
self.create_network()  

self.load_weights(weights_file)

self.cuda(device=0)  # assumes GPU and uses one. This is probably suboptimal
self.eval()  # prediction mode
```

What I can gather from the lightning docs, I can pretty much do the same, except not to do the `cuda()` call. So something like:

```
self.create_network()

self.load_weights(weights_file)
self.freeze()  # prediction mode
```

So, my first question is whether this is the correct way to use lightning? How would lightning know if it needs to use the GPU? I am guessing this needs to be specified somewhere.

Now, for the prediction, I have the following setup:

```
def infer(frame):
    img = transform(frame)  # apply some transformation to the input
    img = torch.from_numpy(img).float().unsqueeze(0).cuda(device=0)
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = self.__call__(Variable(img)).data.cpu().numpy()
    return output
```

This is the bit that has me confused. Which functions do I need to override to make a lightning compatible prediction?

Also, at the moment, the input comes as a numpy array. Is that something that would be possible from the lightning module or do things always have to use some sort of a dataloader?

At some point, I want to extend this model implementation to do training as well, so want to make sure I do it right but while most examples focus on training models, a simple example of just doing prediction at production time on a single image/data point might be useful.

I am using 0.7.5 with pytorch 1.4.0 on GPU with cuda 10.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LightningModule` is a subclass of `torch.nn.Module` so the same model class will work for both inference and training. For that reason, you should probably call the `cuda()` and `eval()` methods outside of `__init__`.

Since it's just a `nn.Module` under the hood, once you've loaded your weights you don't need to override any methods to perform inference, simply call the model instance. Here's a toy example you can use:

```py
import torchvision.models as models
from pytorch_lightning.core import LightningModule

class MyModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resnet = models.resnet18(pretrained=True, progress=False)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.resnet(x)

model = MyModel().eval().cuda(device=0)
```

And then to actually run inference you don't need a method, just do something like:

```py
for frame in video:
    img = transform(frame)
    img = torch.from_numpy(img).float().unsqueeze(0).cuda(0)
    output = model(img).data.cpu().numpy()
    # Do something with the output
```

The main benefit of PyTorchLighting is that you can also use the same class for training by implementing `training_step()`, `configure_optimizers()` and `train_dataloader()` on that class. You can find a simple example of that in the [PyTorchLightning docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lightning-module.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even though above answer suffices, if one takes note of following line

```py
img = torch.from_numpy(img).float().unsqueeze(0).cuda(0)
```

One has to put both the model as well as image to the right GPU. On multi-gpu inference machine, this becomes a hassle.

To solve this, `.predict` was also recently produced, see more at https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy/production_basic.html